# Has anyone used a Disruptor port in C# with success?

Tags: .net, concurrency, trading, circular-buffer

[Disruptor](http://code.google.com/p/disruptor/) has been proven successful in the Java world, in particular by [LMAX](http://www.lmaxtrader.co.uk/), the group responsible. Has anyone used a .NET port with success (alpha, beta, or production) in a trading scenario or other domain? If so, how has it been successful and why did you choose the port you did?